# C# How to keep Selenium WebElement in memory to have time to get its details

Tags: c#, html, selenium, dom

I'm trying to spy a web site with Selenium and C# to watch if new items appears on it.
Inside this web site, I have a list of `<div class="myClass">` elements displayed like a table with many sub divs.
Periodically, I read all displayed divs and check if a new one is present.
But the number of divs is limited and when a new element appears, the oldest one is removed and it making an issue on my code.

Example: *The max number of items is 3.*

1. I get 3 items **A,B,C**.
2. a new item **D** appears.
3. I read the 3 displayed items: when I'm reading all sub div of **D**, a new item **E** comes and **D** is moved and I get an error like "Element is no longer attached to the DOM"

I get this error because the reading of all **D** sub divs is too long.

I'm getting the webelement using `FindElement(By.Name("elemName")`
There is a way to keep the element in memory even if this one is move or removed from the DOM?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the C# code you are using, and the HTML structure as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting problem that I've run into in the past. Through a few frustrating debugging sessions, I found that my `WebElement` objects were dynamically changing based on what was visible on the page. I would retrieve a `List<WebElement>`, change something on the page, and notice that my `List<>` would actually change with the contents on the page.

To answer your question.....I'm not totally sure if this is possible, to store the `WebElement` itself, without removing the old `div` as you mentioned.

The only workaround I would suggest to this is creating your own `Element` class and assigning `WebElements` to this class so you can basically create your own "cache" of elements.

Here's a little sample:

```
public class Element
{
    public string TagName { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool Displayed { get; set; }
    // any other attributes you want to store here
}

public List<Element> StoreWebElements(List<IWebElement> seleniumElements)
{
    var result = new List<Element>();
    foreach (var elem in seleniumElements)
    {
       result.Add(new Element { TagName = elem.TagName,
                                Text = elem.Text, 
                                Displayed = elem.Displayed
                               };
    }
}


// your code
var divList = Driver.FindElements(By.Name("elemName"));

// "store" the elements
var cachedElements = StoreWebElements(divList);

// do something on the page to change it 
// divList will change, but cachedElements will stay the same.
```

It's a bit of a hacky solution, but I personally never found a workaround to the issue that you have described. I would be curious to see if anyone else has an explanation or better solution for this.